# react-router-dom "No match 404" get rendered when going to a path with "useParams"

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using the react-router-dom No Match404 and It works fine But When going to a path a with useParams it renders the 404 page heres the Code:

```
{/* Here it works fine it renders the routes */}
<Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
<Route path='/help' component={Help} /> 
<Route path='/signup' component={Signup} />

{/* The 404 page that render when a path does not exists */}
<Route component={Page404} />

{/* but when I try to render the route with useParams which is the uid I get from firebase it just render the Page404 */}
<Route path='/user/:uid' component={Profile} />

{/*-----------------Profile page------------------------*/}
// heres the profile page that uses useParams

import { useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import {auth} from './firebase/config'

function Profile() {

  let { uid } = useParams();

  // here I have a variable that get a signed in user Unique Id from firebase 

  const [userId, setUserId] = useState('') 
  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User logged in already or has just logged in.
    setUserId(user.uid);
  } else {
    // User not logged in or has just logged out.
  }
 });

if (uid === userId ) {
  return <div>This is your profile</div>
}else{
  return <div>This is someone elses or it does not exist</div> 
}


}
```

This code works well when I remove the 404 Route but when I put it, the Profile route render the 404 page.

is there a way to have 404 page but only renders when the route actually does not exist.

Comment: Have you tried to put the 404 routing at the end, after all other routes.

Comment: Hi @JiaSH thank you for your response, Yeah I tried still didn't work

Comment: Please share a more complete and comprehensive code example. What `useParams` hook are you referring to? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have a general path like `404` for example here, you have to add `exact` prop to your other routes to make them more specific.

like this:

```
{/* but when I try to render the route with useParams which is the uid I get from firebase it just render the Page404 */}
<Route exact path='/user/:uid' component={Profile} />

{/* The 404 page that render when a path does not exists */}
<Route component={Page404} />
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried it like that it didn't work

Comment: @MinenhleSolsonCele I forgot to say that your 404 `Route` should be the last `Route`

Comment: Yeah that actually worked thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check This [No Match (404)](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match)

or **you can you implement like this**

This means if the routes above haven’t matched, the only possible solution is we’ve hit a route that doesn’t actually exist.

```html
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Hello} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, that was the documentation I was following and   didn't work,

Comment: Your `404` route should be the `last Route`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've rendered your routes into a `Switch` component then you need to keep in mind that when ***exclusively*** matching/rendering routes that route path order and specificity matters! This is because the `Switch` component matches and renders *the **first** child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location.*

[Switch](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)

> `<Switch>` is unique in that it renders a route *exclusively*. In
> contrast, every `<Route>` that matches the location renders *inclusively*.

If you list your less specific paths first they will be matched and rendered. You should order the paths in inverse order of specificity. If done correctly there is nearly* a 0% use case for needing the `exact` prop (*it's more useful when **inclusively** matching routes within a router*).

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/user/:uid' component={Profile} />
  <Route path='/help' component={Help} /> 
  <Route path='/signup' component={Signup} />
  <Route path='/' exact component={Home} /> // *
  <Route component={Page404} />
</Switch>
```

* `exact` prop used on the home `"/"` path to keep it from matching any other non-homepage component.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have another block ex. `<Layout>`, make sure you don't put any block between `<Switch>` and `<Route>`

```
<Switch>
    <Layout>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Hello} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Layout>
</Switch>
```

into

```
<Layout>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Hello} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
</Layout>
```